# Object to string, and vice-versa

Tags: javascript, object, type-conversion

Say I had the object:

```
var object = {
    1: [2,5,"hi"],
    hi: {hihi: 1}
};
```

How would I convert that to a string, and then back, preserving all the information? I would need this to work for a *big* object, with the values themselves being objects.

*This is not a duplicate, the others didn't involve getting the object back.*

Comment: [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) is your friend!

Comment: Voting to reopen as not a duplicate because the supposed duplicate is about converting an object to a string, and this question is about how to convert and then retrieve. None of the answers in the duplicate mention `JSON.parse()`, which is an important part of the answer to this question.

Comment: @Vohuman You made a bad decision, next time please be more careful with your close votes.

Comment: What makes it "bad"? Since the question has 3 open votes I'll reopen it!

Comment: @Vohuman He wanted a 2-way conversion, while the dupe was only unidirectional. Thank you the reopening, and that you'd hear us.

Comment: "I do not enlighten those who are not eager to learn, nor arouse those who are not anxious to give an explanation themselves. If I have presented one corner of the square and they cannot come back to me with the other three, I should not go over the points again."

– Confucius

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below is a **live demo** of how you can convert an object to a string and back using [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Open your browser console and you can see that all attributes are preserved after the conversion to a string and back.

```js
var object = {
    1: [2,5,"hi"],
    hi: {hihi: 1}
};

console.log(object);

var strobj = JSON.stringify(object);

console.log(strobj);

var unstrobj = JSON.parse(strobj);

console.log(unstrobj);
```